# how to open windows shared folder

Tags: networking

I am running Ubuntu 13.04.

I want to open a shared folder in other window PC, with ip address like 192.168.11.10, where a shared document is located.

Doing it from Brows Network shows error.

Comment: to use a windows share, there are a few workaround to use them in Ubuntu. Depending whether you want to mount it at start-up or not, I can recommend you the following Ubuntu community documentation: Permanent mount: [1] https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the Computer icon on the desktop. From the drop-down list, choose Map Network Drive. Select a drive letter that you want to apply to access the shared folder and then type in the UNC path to the folder. UNC path is just a specific format for pointing to a folder on another computer.

Comment: Is this an answer when using Windows? Because this is about (a very old version of) Ubuntu.